# how to remove space characters (" ")in a list {PYTHON}

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Im trying to write a for loop to remove space characters (" ") in my list but it's just deleting some of the characters that are in the first of my lsit

this is my list

`mylist=[" "," "," "," ","oho","abcd","1234",1234," "," ","omg"]`

and this is my loop

```
for i in mylist:
    if i==' ':
        mylist.remove(i)
```

but when I print mylist I get this

`[' ', 'oho', 'abcd', '1234', 1234, ' ', ' ', 'omg']`

and I'm expecting this

`['oho', 'abcd', '1234', 1234, 'omg']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is with list compehension:

```
mylist=[" "," "," "," ","oho","abcd","1234",1234," "," ","omg"]
new_list=[x for x in mylist if x != " "]
print(new_list) # prints ['oho', 'abcd', '1234', 1234, 'omg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) ?

Just in case, if the reason you have such a list to begin with is that you were attempting to split a string while discarding *all* whitespace, but used `str.split()`, you may want to try `re.split` instead:

```py
>>> import re
>>> data = '        oho abcd 1234     omg'
>>> re.split("\s+", data.strip())
['oho', 'abcd', '1234', 'omg']
```

Comment: In the OP's case, the list contains mixed types, strings and `int`s.